# Using Java application to open browser tabs

Tags: java, macos

I am thinking to make a java application that will take as an input different URLS and open them automatically on new browser tabs.I do know how to make it work up to the point where a tab is opened .Is that process something too complicated ? What should i look to in order to learn how to do it  ?Thanks for any help.

Note this is for OSX

Comment: Do you mean Javascript? Or Java applets?

Comment: Well im not sure what would be needed for that and thats the reason im
asking. I know some Java but not java script. The application doesnt need to be part of the browser . Im thinking of making a simple swing gui where i put in the urls hit a button and tabs open. :) I just have no idea where or what i should read on how to open tabs.

Comment: Do you mean, something like [URLOpener](http://www.urlopener.com), but as a Java application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to invoke any command from the Java application. In your case it can be the browser.

Here is the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: That sounds like something i could use . So if i find the command to open a tab from terminal im basically there.

Comment: You beat me to it.  Here is a link to the command line arguments for  firefox: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments

Answer (score 1):

To handle this in a somewhat OS independent manner, you could try [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29). But the requirement of all URI's in the same tab can't be done this way, AFAIK.

Comment: Doesnt need to be OS independent its only something that i want for personal use. Im sure that there are ready programs out there for that but i want to do it my self. Thanks for your advice .

Comment: @latusaki, in that case, you might want to include your OS in the tags. Or at least mention it in your original question.

Comment: If the browser has a "open all new windows in new tabs" option, this is probably the way to go. Not sure about Safari or IE but this should definitely work for Firefox